# Seminorms: Absolute Convexity

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

*This is a preparation for: [Gauges vs. Cylinders](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1182888/79762)*

Given a vector space $\Omega$.

One has the equivalence:
$$U\text{ absolutely convex}\iff U\text{ balanced, convex}$$

Moreover, it holds the equivalence:
$$\kappa U+\lambda U\subseteq U\quad(|\kappa|+|\lambda|\leq1)\iff\kappa U+\lambda U=(|\kappa|+|\lambda|)U$$

How to prove this from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand one has:
$$(1-s)A+sA\subseteq A\quad(0\leq s\leq1)\quad\rho A+0A\subseteq A\quad(|\rho|\leq1)$$

On the other hand one has:
$$\kappa A+\lambda A\subseteq\frac{|\kappa|}{|\kappa|+|\lambda|}A+\frac{|\lambda|}{|\kappa|+|\lambda|}A\subseteq A\quad(|\kappa|+|\lambda|)$$

Now, it always holds:
$$(\kappa+\lambda)A\subseteq\kappa A+\lambda A$$

So one has equality here:
$$\kappa A+\lambda A\subseteq(|\kappa|+|\lambda|)A\subseteq|\kappa|A+|\lambda|A\subseteq\kappa A+\lambda A$$

Hence it also holds:
$$1A-1A=0A$$

Thus one has inclusion here:
$$\rho A\subseteq\rho A+(1-|\rho|)A=A\quad(|\rho|\leq1)$$
That sets the converse!