# Seminorms: Gauges vs. Cylinders

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

*This is a preparation for: [Continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1182724/79762)*

Given a vector space $\Omega$.

Consider seminorms:
$$\mu:V\to\mathbb{R}_+:\quad\mu(\lambda v)=|\lambda|v\quad\mu(u+v)\leq\mu(u+v)$$

Consider absolutely convex absorbers:
$$U\subseteq\Omega:\quad\kappa U+\lambda U=(|\kappa|+|\lambda|)U\quad\left(\bigcup_{r>0}rU=\Omega\right)$$

Introduce cylinder sets:
$$B_\mu(\varepsilon):=\{\mu<\varepsilon\}\quad\overline{B}_\mu(\varepsilon):=\{\mu\leq\varepsilon\}$$
*(These are absorbing, balanced and convex.)*

Introduce Minkowski gauges:
$$\mu_U(x):=\inf\{r\geq0:x\in rU\}$$
*(These are finite, positive, homogeneous and subadditive.)*

One has the manipulation:
$$B_\mu(\varepsilon)=\varepsilon B_\mu(1)\quad\overline{B}_\mu(\varepsilon)=\varepsilon\overline{B}_\mu(1)$$

Then they're in 1-1 correspondence:
$$\mu_{B_\mu(1)}\equiv\mu\equiv\mu_{\overline{B}_\mu(1)}$$
$$B_{\mu_U}(1)\subseteq U\subseteq\overline{B}_{\mu_U}(1)$$

How to prove this from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly one has:
$$\mu(x)<\varepsilon\iff\mu(\varepsilon^{-1}x)<1$$

So the cylinders are absorbing:
$$\varepsilon_x:=\mu(x)+1:\quad x\in B_\mu(\varepsilon_x)=\frac{\varepsilon_x}{\varepsilon}B_\mu(\varepsilon)$$

Also they're balanced:
$$x\in B_\mu(\varepsilon):\quad\mu(\rho x)\leq|\rho|\mu(x)<\varepsilon\quad(|\rho|\leq1)$$

Moreover they're convex:
$$x,y\in B_\mu(\varepsilon):\quad\mu((1-s)x+sy)\leq(1-s)\mu(x)+s\mu(y)<\varepsilon\quad(0\leq s\leq1)$$

The gauges are finite:
$$\{r\geq0:x\in rA\}\neq\varnothing$$

Also they're homogeneous:
$$\lambda x\in\lambda(\mu_U(x)+\delta)U\subseteq|\lambda|(\mu_U(x)+\delta)U$$
$$x\in\frac{1}{\lambda}(\mu_U(\lambda x)+\delta)U\subseteq\frac{1}{|\lambda|}(\mu_U(\lambda x)+\delta)U$$

Moreover they're subadditive:
$$x+y\in(\mu_U(x)+\delta)U+(\mu_U(y)+\delta)U=(\mu_U(x)+\mu_U(y)+2\delta)U$$

Now the first correspondence holds since:
$$\mu_U(x)<\mu_U(x)+\delta\implies x\in(\mu_{B_\mu(1)}(x)+\delta)B_\mu(1)\implies\mu(x)\leq\mu_U(x)+\delta$$
$$\mu(x)<\mu(x)+\delta\implies x\in(\mu(x)+\delta)B_\mu(1)\implies\mu_U(x)\leq\mu(x)+\delta$$

And the second correspondence holds since:
$$x\in B_{\mu_U}(1)\implies x\in(\mu_U(x)+\delta)U\subseteq U$$
$$x\in U\implies\mu_U(x)\leq1\implies x\in\overline{B}_{\mu_U}(1)$$

This completes the investigation!